# I want to Run Scripts in to Html after load data with Jquery.ajax method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to Run Scripts in to Html after load data with Jquery.ajax method

```
 $.ajax({
     url: '',
     type: 'Get',
     success: function(data)
     {
          var scripts = ???? // here i want get Scripts
     }
 })
```

Comment: [$.getScript() --  Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Comment: my content is a HTML and javascript not ..js file

Comment: what is your purpose.... ? why are you doing such a thing

Comment: i have dynamic javascript into html

Answer (score 0):

i Can Find this

```
$.ajax({ 
url : '',
type: 'get',
success : function(data)
  {
     var element = document.createElement('div');
     element.innerHTML = data;
     var scripts = element.getElementsByTagName('script');
     for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++)
        eval(scripts[i].text);
  }
})
```